# Parsing Json - Displays different order when running code

Tags: java

I'm extremely new to Java, and I'm currently working on a Project that involves reading a json file and putting it into objects. I have so far managed to do parts of it however, I have noticed that I'm unable to read to the end of the file, I think this is because of the extra varaibles that I haven't included such as platforms, and expected, and the odd additional depature. So far, I have managed to read the data in but I have noticed that it comes up In the wrong order...
Below is a "Short" extract of the Json file that I have.

`[{"stops":[{"name":"Totnes","arrives":"0959","departs":"1000"},{"name":"Ivybridge","arrives":"1016","departs":"1016"},{"name":"Plymouth","arrives":"1029","departs":"1033"},{"name":"Saltash","arrives":"1041","departs":"1042"},{"name":"St Germans","arrives":"1048","departs":"1049"},{"name":"Liskeard","arrives":"1100","departs":"1101"},{"name":"Bodmin Parkway","arrives":"1115","departs":"1117"},{"name":"Par","arrives":"1127","departs":"1128"},{"name":"St Austell","arrives":"1135","departs":"1136"},{"name":"Truro","arrives":"1152","departs":"1153"},{"name":"Redruth","arrives":"1206","departs":"1207"},{"name":"Camborne","arrives":"1212","departs":"1213"},{"name":"Hayle","arrives":"1220","departs":"1220"},{"name":"St Erth","arrives":"1224","departs":"1225"},{"name":"Penzance","arrives":"1234","departs":null}],"platform":"2","departs":"0947"}'

I don't understand why when I run my code, it displays arrives first followed by the name followed by the departs? I don't see where I'm going wrong. Here is my code to my program...

JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

```
   try  {
       URL jsonUrl = new URL(url);

       BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(jsonUrl.openStream()));
       String inputLine;
       JSONArray result = new JSONArray();


       while ((inputLine = input.readLine()) != null) {
           Object obj = parser.parse(inputLine); 
           JSONArray TrainList = (JSONArray) obj;
           result.addAll(TrainList);

       }

       //Read JSON API



       System.out.println(result);

       //Iterate over trainlist array
       result.forEach(stop -> parseNameObject( ( JSONObject) stop) );


   } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
   }



    }

   private static void parseNameObject(JSONObject Trains)
   {
       //Get Stop object within list
       JSONArray stopObject = (JSONArray) Trains.get("stops");

       JSONObject name = (JSONObject) stopObject.get(0);
       if (name != null) {
           System.out.println(name.toString());
       }
```

I'm really intrested to see where I'm going wrong as I've spent many hours over it and can't find a thing!

Comment: Is this a self-written JSONParser? If so, I would encourage you to use an already-existing tool, like [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) or [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson).

Comment: It's self written, I used imports from simple json. I'll try to use Jackson tomorrow! 